# Python FeatureClass To Geodatabase conversion Issue

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

When I run this part of my code, I get an error that says the parameters of the MakeFeatureLayer are not valid.  However, when I run the first half of this script (the first try/except) and then run only the second part of the script, the code works, but errors if I run it all together. I'm guessing it is a workspace issue, but I can't figure it out.

```
import arcpy
import math

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


pth = "C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/"
outname = "Family_" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + ".gdb"

arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + ".gdb"

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(pth, outname, "CURRENT")


wkspce = "C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/master_data"

arcpy.env.workspace = wkspce

try:

    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcs:
        arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fc, pth + outname)
except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()


pth1 = "C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/"
outname1 = "Family_" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + ".gdb"
param1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
famloc = "family_location_"
family = "Featured_Family_Location_updated"
```

arcpy.env.workspace = pth1 + outname1

```
try:
    defquery = '"Family_ID" = ' + "'" + param1 + "'"
    featurein = pth1 + outname1 + "/" + family
    layer = "family_lyr"
    copyname = pth1 + outname1 + "/" + famloc + param1


    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(featurein,layer,defquery) 
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, copyname)

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
##
```

This is the error :

ERROR 000732: Workspace or Feature Dataset: Dataset C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/Family_C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Ever‌​ything/PSU/GEOG_596A/master_data\tracts.shp.gdb does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, @GeoStoneMarten.

Comment: what object are you passing in arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) ?

Comment: Individual letters.  In this case, the letter "D", typed into pythonwin as D

Comment: I recommend removing try/except when testing/posting code snippets here because it can mask valuable error messages.

Comment: Are you showing us the complete code? Where is "tracts.shp" comming from?

Comment: I have check and it run. See my answers

Comment: @Hornbydd, I convert shapefiles to the created gdb from a folder.  The tracts.shp is in the master_data folder.  For some reason, when I try to save my layer (after a query), the script is somehow pulling that shapefile and messing up the paths...and I'll remind you that the code works if I break it in half.  In other words, I comment out the second section and run the first part just fine.  Then I comment out the first part and run the second, and it runs perfectly.  It is when I try to run it all together that it errors.

Comment: Your parameter is not what you think it is. Just insert print arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) somewhere in your code, and you'll see that it's C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Ever‌​ything/PSU/GEOG_596A/master_data\tracts.shp

Comment: @Tom I think this is a featurelayer in first workspace and this is return by arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

Comment: @Hornbydd same remark as the previous comment

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten It should turn up there too, but the relevant matter is it is also the parameter, because it is being concatenated with some other junk and assigned to outname1. Hence the pretty clear error message.

Comment: I think this is problem of assignment with global parameter I have change the part of code in last answer. the parameter is just a character """Individual letters. In this case, the letter "D", typed into pythonwin as D – Dane """

Comment: The arcpy.GetParameterAsText() changes to the weird concatenated string after the shapefiles are exported to the gdb...(FeatureClasstoGeodatabase)...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` returns the text FRED then `featurein` would be:

"C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/Family_FRED.gdb/Featured_Family_Location_updated"

So does the Featureclass *Featured_Family_Location_updated* exist in that GeoDatabase, if not thats your problem.

Comment: Yes, it is there.  That is the strange thing.   This is the error I get: ERROR 000732: Workspace or Feature Dataset: Dataset C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/Family_C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/master_data\tracts.shp.gdb does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).   The script is somehow mashing together paths/ shapefiles from the previous workspace with the featureclasses in the latter workspace...

Comment: @Dane please include your precise error message in your question.

Comment: I have same error when passing last layer in ArcMap pyhton window; Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 2, in <module> File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1697, in FeatureClassToGeodatabase raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset xxx_yyy_aaa does not exist or is not supported. I have resolve problem. arcpy.env.workspace need to be the same as ListFeatureClasses() object.

Comment: Don't switch the workspace with arcpy.env.workspace = pth1 + outname1. This is causing your error because it is invalid path. Python uses double back slashes or forward slash or the path flag "r" in front of the path string.  After generating the shapefile list set the workspace to outname. In general use os.path to create your references to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

I have change the script to this:

```
import arcpy

def createGDB(path, name):
""" Create File GDB """

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(path, name, 'CURRENT')

def main(character):
    pth = 'C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/'
    outname = "Family_{}.gdb".format(character)
    createGDB(pth,outname)

    # Get list of in_fc
    arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/Users/Dane/Desktop/Everything/PSU/GEOG_596A/master_data'  # I think it contains shapefile
    print "source directory :\r\n{}{}".format(pth,outname)
    fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    print 'Insert data in gdb :\r\n{}{}'.format(pth,outname)
    out_wk = "{}{}".format(pth,outname)

    try:
        # set output with overwrite param
        # arccy.env.workspace = out_wk
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1  # I don't think it's needed because
                                       # process create exist_name_1
                                       # next pass exist_name_1_1

        # test insert dataset
        for fc in fcs:
            print "push fc : {}".format(fc)
            arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fc,out_wk)
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         main(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
```

Can you test it? I have just a problem with one featureclass. I don't know why and check it with toolbox directly. I comeback later and comment problem with other test.

Comment: the error is arrived when the env.workspace is different of arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(). It continu to check in env.workspace. But this error don't arrived a the first featureclass contanied in list. It is not easy to understand because it arrived at the third featureclass  i want to convert if env.workspace point to an other path (not the same as fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()). I think arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1isn't necessary because replacement isn't possible and it create <fcname>+"_1" ...